# in Ubuntu 14.04.3 UCK tool,I can't install wine 1.6 or wine1.7

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, wine, uck

I can install `wine1.7` successfully by following commond,but  can't install in `uck tool`

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
# apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.7 : Depends: wine1.7-i386 (= 1:1.7.44-0ubuntu1) but it is not installable
           Recommends: gnome-exe-thumbnailer but it is not going to be installed or
                       kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-horai-umefont but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-unfonts-core but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-wqy-microhei
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: use `aptitude` maybe works, it'll recommend good ways

Answer (score 0):

i have same problem.
If you using ubuntu > 14.04, try this:

```
sudo apt-cache policy libvpx1

libvpx1:
Installed: 1.3.0+git20150219-1~gd~t
Candidate: 1.3.0+git20150219-1~gd~t
Version table:
*** 1.3.0+git20150219-1~gd~t 0
    100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
 1.3.0-3~trusty 0
    500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mc3man/trusty-media/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
 1.3.0-2 0
    500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

And downgrade this package:

```
sudo apt-get install libvpx1=1.3.0-3~trusty
```